# Force cargo version with Yocto

Tags: rust, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to use **rust** with **bitbake/yocto** using the `meta-rust` layer.

Within the layer itself I can see that a recipe for **cargo** version 1.58.0 was recently added. Unfortunately when I try and build any **rust** code Using BitBake I get the following error:

```
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: echo-server-0.1.0.AUTOINC+c37d3bb2f3-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('./tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/echo-server/0.1.0.AUTOINC+c37d3bb2f3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.391773', 101, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ./tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/echo-server/0.1.0.AUTOINC+c37d3bb2f3-r0/temp/log.do_compile.391773
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: cargo = build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/echo-server/0.1.0.AUTOINC+c37d3bb2f3-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/cargo
| NOTE: rustc =
| NOTE: cargo build -v --target x86_64-poky-linux --release --manifest-path=./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/echo-server/0.1.0.AUTOINC+c37d3bb2f3-r0/git//Cargo.toml
| error: failed to parse manifest at ./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/echo-server/0.1.0.AUTOINC+c37d3bb2f3-r0/git/Cargo.toml
|
| Caused by:
|   feature `edition2021` is required
|
|   consider adding `cargo-features = ["edition2021"]` to the manifest
| WARNING: exit code 101 from a shell command.
```

The rust code builds fine on the local system and I believe the error is because the version of **cargo** being used by **yocto** is 1.54

```
tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/libstd-rs/1.54.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/cargo --version

cargo 1.54.0
```

How do I get **yocto** to use the later version of **cargo**? The recipe exists in `meta-rust` and I can see **yocto** knows about it via

```
bitbake -s | grep cargo

cargo                                              :1.58.1-r0
cargo-cross-canadian-x86-64                        :1.58.1-r0
cargo-native                                       :1.58.1-r0                :1.54.0-r0
nativesdk-cargo                                    :1.58.1-r0
```

Note if set `RUSTVERSION ?= "1.58"` I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: preferred version 1.58 of cargo-native not available (for item cargo-native)
WARNING: versions of cargo-native available: 1.54.0
WARNING: preferred version 1.58 of libstd-rs not available (for item libstd-rs)
WARNING: versions of libstd-rs available: 1.54.0
WARNING: preferred version 1.58 of libstd-rs not available (for item libstd-rs)
WARNING: versions of libstd-rs available: 1.54.0
WARNING: preferred version 1.58 of libstd-rs not available (for item libstd-rs-dev)
WARNING: versions of libstd-rs available: 1.54.0
WARNING: preferred version 1.58 of rust-native not available (for item rust-native)
WARNING: versions of rust-native available: 1.54.0
WARNING: preferred version 1.58 of rust-llvm-native not available (for item rust-llvm-native)
WARNING: versions of rust-llvm-native available: 1.54.0
```

Which indicates it is defaulting to version 1.54.0

Note: `bitbake -c cleanall rust cargo` produces the following errors:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'rust'
rust was skipped: Rust recipe doesn't work for target builds at this time. Fixes welcome.
```

Comment: Similar question (by me) here https://github.com/rust-embedded/meta-rust-bin/issues/89, should work for you case (remove the `-bin`)

Comment: BTW: If you are on honister or later, the meta-rust layer has included into poky itself, no need for an additional layer anymore. The variable is called `RUSTVERSION` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about honister, I have removed my explicit cone of the `meta-rust` layer. Unfortunately if I set `RUSTVERSION` to `1.58` the build produces a lot of warning when checking dependencies and eventually fails when fetching `cargo-native`. For now my workaround is to set edition to 2018 in my `Cargo.toml` file.

Comment: Having the recipe and source in separate repos is very cumbersome - is there a way of including the recipe alongside the rust source?

Comment: Without any further information about your warnings I cannot tell you what's going on. Maybe use a `bitbake -c cleanall rust cargo` and maybe the native packages as well. I would never recommend mixing recipes and source. One hasn't to do anything with the other!  But there's [cargo-bitbake](https://github.com/meta-rust/cargo-bitbake) and case you didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done in bitbake via [PREFERRED_VERSION_foo](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/singleindex.html#term-PREFERRED_VERSION) it looks like meta-rust includes a file that does this change for you:

https://github.com/meta-rust/meta-rust/blob/c654f5cb928bd4f4c7da7d74a8356fd2a94283f6/conf/distro/include/rust_versions.inc#L4

```
RUST_VERSION ?= "1.58"
```

if you **include this file in your distro.conf** (or local.conf) and change line #4 to match version 1.58, you should be able to use/build cargo version 1.58

You could still manually change `PREFERRED_VERSION_cargo/rust*` on your local.conf but you;d have to do it for all the rust components, just like the rust_versions.inc file is doing it.

Comment: Thanks - just tried adding `RUST_VERSION ?= "1.58"` to local.conf but it makes no difference and still uses version 1.54.

Comment: Adding RUST_VERSION to local.conf wont do anything by itself, you MUST to that along with adding an include/require for the `distro/include/rust_versions.inc` file

Comment: Sorry I don't follow - as I am using Hoister I have removed the meta-rust clone and I cannot find a "rust_versions.inc" file in any other layer. My current workaround of using an older version of rust/Cargo works for now but I imagine that will be probable mantic going forwards. As a project we may have to abandon Rust and stick with C/C++ (and revisit at a. later date when the tools are more mature).